# How to convert a TeX file with custom commands into LyX?

Tags: lyx, conversion

LyX doesn't understand certain pieces of a .tex file when it converts it into .lyx via `tex2lyx` program. For instance:

```
\rowcolors{1}{gray!15}{white}
```

If this line is present in the .tex file, LyX imports it as a mix of tex code and simple text:

[image]

How to convert this case properly? Apart from using `\input` and `\include` for each line of code? Or using `\input` for the entire block inside `\begin{document}`?

Comment: I can reproduce the issue with `File -> Import -> LaTeX(plain)` which calls tex2lyx under the hood. Perhaps you should report it as a bug.

Comment: `tex2lyx` is too recent tool, search for this issue in the [LyX bug tracker](http://www.lyx.org/trac/wiki/BugTrackerHome) and start a new entry if necessary.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a bug or lacking feature in LyX.